# How to make desktop color by xfconf-query in ubuntu18.04 please?

Tags: ubuntu, colors, desktop

My environment is xubuntu 18.04 64-bit.
I use this to set desktop's color:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/color1 -n -t int -t int -t int -t int -s 19018 -s 37008 -s 55769 -s 65535
```

Then I see the color is black. What is my wrong please?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Comment: Thank you.  sorry for my behavior.